# Automatically playing a youtube video in full screen

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using a player to play youtube videos on a web page. The videos are loaded from a channel and played one by one automatically. This is working perfectly. However I want that video should be automatically played in full screen mode.

Here is the code that plays the video:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="player" title="YouTube video player" height="400" width="580" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy =0&amp;allowfullscreen=true&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

As you can see I am using iframe with a standard width and height. Now one solution would be to increase the iframe size and it will do the trick. But I don't want to do that because the page has other content and I don't want to increase the size that it collides with other content. I want my video to go into full screen automatically on loading and when escape key is pressed it will return back to small size (that is default full screen option).

Thanks
Ahmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. You cannot interact with a flash object unless you have the original .fla file . A restriction from flash